# node-fetch error while loading trained model in tensorflow.js

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, tensorflow.js

After training my tensorflow model, I converted it to the json format as required by tensorflow.js. However when I tried to load this model using javascript, I get a `node-fetch` error.

This is my code :

```
const tf = require("./tf.min.js");
(async function () {
  const modelURL = "model_js/model.json";
  const model = await tf.loadLayersModel(modelURL);
  model.summary();
})();
```

Complete error logs :

```
(node:35092) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Cannot find module 'node-fetch'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:582:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:508:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
    at pw (/Users/suraj/Desktop/fake-news/tf.min.js:17:225676)
    at t.e.fetch (/Users/suraj/Desktop/fake-news/tf.min.js:17:225911)
    at t.<anonymous> (/Users/suraj/Desktop/fake-news/tf.min.js:17:255546)
    at u (/Users/suraj/Desktop/fake-news/tf.min.js:17:104674)
    at Generator._invoke (/Users/suraj/Desktop/fake-news/tf.min.js:17:104427)
    at Generator.forEach.t.(anonymous function) [as next] (/Users/suraj/Desktop/fake-news/tf.min.js:17:105031)
(node:35092) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 3)
(node:35092) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Answer (score 0):

The module is not imported correctly. You most probably is importing a minified script that is intended to run in the browser. The [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/js/tutorials/setup) covers how to get started with tensorflow.js

Install the package:

```
npm install @tensorflow/tfjs
```

Usage

```
import * as tf from '@tensorflow/tfjs';
```